# Am I allowed to use the JavaMail API for a commercial project?

Tags: java, licensing, jakarta-mail

The JavaMail API's license agreement is so confusing since I am not a lawyer.

I want to use JavaMail for a closed-source, commercial project on the server-side of an email service, which offers email functionality to our customers.

So, am I allowed to use JavaMail or do I have to pay a license fee or release my code under an open-source license or something like that?

Comment: It wouldn't hurt to vote now and again, too.

Comment: Sorry, not used to that :-). Added accepts now.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because **it is about licensing or legal issues**, not programming or software development. [See here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/274964/1402846) for details, and the [help/on-topic] for more.

Comment: @KevinBrown I agree that it's offtopic and I'd close the question but it seems like some ppl appreciate the answer. Is there a way to move this question somewhere to reopen it so ppl and can still access it?

Comment: The licenses listed for the Java Mail API JAR are CDDL & GPL 2.0.  You should read about those and consult with legal counsel to understand what that means.  Yes, they are free, but that doesn't mean you should put them into a commercial product without understanding the licenses.

Comment: You can also look here for a summary to get an idea of what your obligations may be:  https://tldrlegal.com/license/common-development-and-distribution-license-(cddl-1.0)-explained https://tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v2

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The most important thing to respect is probably this statement:

> You acknowledge that Software is not designed, licensed or intended for use in the design, construction, operation or maintenance of any **nuclear facility**

Seriously, here is what can be found in the [FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/faq-135477.html):

> Q: Is the JavaMail API implementation
> completely free? Can I ship it along
> with my product?
>
> A: **Yes**. The current
> release of the JavaMail API
> implementation, is completely free and
> you can include it in your product.
> This release includes IMAP, POP3, and
> SMTP providers as well. Please do read
> the license and ensure that you
> understand it. (The license is
> available after clicking the Download
> button on the download page.) The
> JavaBeans Activation Framework is also
> free for use under a similar license.

Comment: hahaha, that piece is nice. But anyway, they aren't plenty of such APIs available. To my knowledge there's only commons-email, which sits ontop of this one

Comment: I just updated my answer because I found the answer in the FAQ.

Comment: For anybody who's still interested in this: I contacted Oracle that time and a sales guy told me it's ok.